# Couchbase N1QL - Nest within a Nest

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Nesting within a Nest. 
I've adapted my need into the following restaurant example:

Desired Output:

```
{
  "restaurant": {
    "id": "restaurant1",
    "name": "Foodie",
    "mains": [                          // < main nested in restaurant
      {
        "id": "main1",
        "title": "Steak and Chips",
        "ingredients": [                // < ingredient nested in main (...which is nested in restaurant)
          {
            "id": "ingredient1",
            "title": "steak"
          },
          {
            "id": "ingredient2",
            "title": "chips"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "main2",
        "title": "Fish and Chips",
        "ingredients": [
          {
            "id": "ingredient3",
            "title": "fish"
          },
          {
            "id": "ingredient2",
            "title": "chips"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    "drinks": [ you get the idea ]     // < drink nested in restaurant
  }
}
```

Example Docs:

```
// RESTAURANTS
{
  "id": "restaurant1",
  "type": "restaurant",
  "name": "Foodie",
  "drinkIds": [ "drink1", "drink2" ],
  "mainIds: [ "main1", "main2" ]
},
// MAINS
{
  "id": "main1",
  "type": "main",
  "restaurantIds": [ "restaurant1" ],
  "title": "Steak and Chips"
},
{
  "id": "main2",
  "type": "main",
  "restaurantIds": [ "restaurant1" ],
  "title": "Fish and Chips"
},
// INGREDIENTS
{
  "id": "ingredient1",
  "type": "ingredient",
  "title": "steak",
  "mainIds": [ "main1" ]
},
{
  "id": "ingredient2",
  "type": "ingredient",
  "title": "chips",
  "mainIds": [ "main1", "main2" ]
},
{
  "id": "ingredient3",
  "type": "ingredient",
  "title": "fish",
  "mainIds": [ "main2" ]
},
// DRINKS
{ you get the idea.... }
```

The closest I can get without error is:

```
SELECT restaurant, mains, drinks
FROM default restauant USE KEYS "restaurant1"
NEST default mains ON KEYS restaurant.mainIds
NEST default drinks ON KEYS restaurant.drinkIds;
```

But:
1. Obviously the nested nest is missing
2. The returned order is incorrect - the drinks nest comes first instead of last
(3. Since I'm also using Sync Gateway - it returns all the "_sync" fields with every doc - can't figure out how to omit this on each doc.)

**UPDATE 1: ADAPTED SOLUTION**
NB: I should have specified above that a *main* cannot hold *ingredientIds*.

Based on geraldss' v helpful input below, I added a doc which tracks keys per restaurant, eg:

```
{ 
  "id": "restaurant1-JoeBloggs",
  "dinerId": "JoeBloggs",
  "ingredientIds": [ "ingredient1", "ingredient2" "ingredient3" ],
  "mainOrdered": [ "main1" ],    // < other potential uses...
  "drinkOrdered": [ "drink2" ]
}
```

I added this to geraldss' first solution below as a JOIN to make it available to the query, eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
    r.*,
    (
        SELECT
            drink.*
        FROM default AS drink
        USE KEYS r.drinkIds
    ) AS drinks,
    (
        SELECT
            main.*,
            (
                SELECT
                  ingredient.*
                  FROM default AS ingredient
                  USE KEYS keyIndex.ingredientIds   // < keyIndex
                  WHERE ingredient.mainId=main.id
            ) AS ingredients
        FROM default AS main
        USE KEYS r.mainIds
    ) AS mains
FROM default AS r
USE KEYS "restaurant1"
JOIN default AS keyIndex ON KEYS "restaurant1-JoeBloggs"   // < keyIndex JOINed
) AS restaurant
;
```

geraldss' second solution below also looks good - unfortunately it won't work for my case as this query requires that mains are found via ingredients; for my needs a main can exist without any ingredients. **EDIT:** > he came up with another solution. See 2.

**UPDATE 2: FINAL SOLUTION**

So, again, with geraldss' help I have a solution which does not require an additional doc to track keys:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
  SELECT
    restaurant.id, restaurant.name,
    (
      SELECT
      drink.id, drink.title
      FROM default AS drink
      USE KEYS restaurant.drinkIds
    ) 
    AS drinks,
    (
      SELECT
      main.id, main.title,
      ARRAY_AGG({"title":ingredient.title, "id":ingredient.id}) AS ingredients
      FROM default AS ingredient
      JOIN default AS main
      ON KEYS ingredient.mainIds
      WHERE main.restaurantId="restaurant1"
      AND meta().id NOT LIKE '_sync:%'                          // < necessary only if using Sync Gateway
      GROUP BY main

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
      mainWithNoIngredients.id, mainWithNoIngredients.title
      FROM default AS mainWithNoIngredients
      UNNEST mainWithNoIngredients AS foo                       // < since this is being flattened the AS name is irrelevant
      WHERE mainWithNoIngredients.restaurantId="restaurant1" 
      AND mainWithNoIngredients.type="main"
      AND meta().id NOT LIKE '_sync:%'                          // < necessary only if using Sync Gateway
      AND META(mainWithNoIngredients).id NOT IN 
      (
        SELECT RAW mainId
        FROM default AS ingredient
      )
    ) 
    AS mains

  FROM default AS restaurant
  USE KEYS "restaurant1"
  ) 
  AS restaurant
;
```

NB - the `AND meta().id NOT LIKE '_sync:%'` lines are only necessary if using Sync Gateway.

With just 1 key I can pull all the related docs - even if they are unknown to the immediate 'parent'.
Thank you geraldss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **mains** contain ingredientIds:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
    r.*,
    (
        SELECT
            drink.*
        FROM default AS drink
        USE KEYS r.drinkIds
    ) AS drinks,
    (
        SELECT
            main.*,
            (
                SELECT
                    ingredient.*
                FROM default AS ingredient
                USE KEYS main.ingredientIds
            ) AS ingredients
        FROM default AS main
        USE KEYS r.mainIds
    ) AS mains
FROM default AS r
USE KEYS "restaurant1"
) AS restaurant
;
```

**EDIT:** Updated to include mains not referenced by any ingredients.

If the **mains** do not contain ingredientIds:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT
    r.*,
    (
        SELECT
            drink.*
    FROM default AS drink
    USE KEYS r.drinkIds
    ) AS drinks,
    (
        SELECT
            main.*,
            ARRAY_AGG(ingredient) AS ingredients
        FROM default AS ingredient
        JOIN default AS main
    ON KEYS ingredient.mainIds
        WHERE "restaurant1" IN main.restaurantIds
        GROUP BY main
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            main.*
        FROM default AS main
        WHERE "restaurant1" IN main.restaurantIds
        AND META(main).id NOT IN (
            SELECT RAW mainId
            FROM default AS ingredient
            UNNEST mainIds AS mainId
        )
    ) AS mains
FROM default AS r
USE KEYS "restaurant1"
) AS restaurant
;
```

Comment: Hi geraldss, Thank you so much for your solutions!
I took your first solution and added a new indexing doc. See above.

When trying your second solution ingredients came back as null. Perhaps the issue is in the line `WHERE "restaurant1" IN main.restaurantIds` ?
When I replace that line with `WHERE ingredient.type="ingredient"` it starts to work, though I think further conditions might be required.
However, even if this query was perfected, it's not appropriate for my case as this query requires that mains are found via ingredients. For my case a main can exist without any ingredients.

Comment: You can add a UNION to that subquery to pick up mains that don't have ingredients.

Comment: Hi @geraldss. Ok. Based on your comment I've been trying to build a query utilising UNION without success. Any chance you can point me in the right direction? 
It would far better if I can avoid using an extra doc just to keep track of keys.

Comment: Thank you geraldss. I think the UNNEST line is in the wrong place? The above didn't work for me, however, my _Update 2_ above produced the desired results. 
I've also made some assumptions in my edited Update 2 - if they are incorrect or misleading please don't hesitate to edit me or let me know.
Wouldn't have got there without your help! Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, glad you have a solution. Not sure why the UNNEST doesn't work for you.